# Lighting a Bathroom Tub?

Tags: bathroom

My upstairs bathroom has a bathtub with no light over it, worse yet, we use a privacy curtain diminishing the light even further. This is a pain, especially when shaving and is generally unpleasant.

What kind of lights can I install, and can a light be placed over a bathtub for illumination?

I was considering also considering installing a bathroom fan, and I'm aware that some of them have lights on them, but everyone I've talked to about this has said that the fan should not be placed directly over the tub (I suppose due to winter drafts?).

What's the best way to light the tub, and what specs should I look for either in lighting or in a humidity extractor?

Bathtub picture with curtain: [image]

Comment: How high is the ceiling over the tub?

Comment: `I suppose due to winter drafts?` .... no ..... `danger of electrocution` .... yes

Comment: Certainly that too!

Comment: i would consider running a bunch of USB powered fairy lights or "xmas" lights; most are waterproof and they can't zap you even if they fall into a full tub. You can get much lighter curtains that preserve privacy as well, that would help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per NEC 410.10.B there is a restricted area 8' above the rim of the tub and this extends 3' to the side of the tub this is why you usually do not see lighting in this location. But it can be done with a fixture listed for wet locations. These fixtures usually seal so water cannot get in. If this is only a tub not a shower a damp location fixture could be used (not getting splashed) but I prefer the wet location fixtures.

Comment: Also, damp or wet certification doesn't imply that the thing won't rust before your very eyes. Look for something of high quality stainless or aluminum, if not plastic.

Comment: It actually is a shower, my bad. So how do people usually get around the lighting issue posed by the shower curtain?

Comment: You can use a listed wet location fixture, for one that looks nice they get spendy in the old enclosed shower stalls years ago a fixture called a jelly jar was common these have a cover that looks like a jelly jar and screws into a seal, some have metal cages but that is not required. Because of cost many times we used to put them outside the tub but the restricted zone was extended 3' outside the tub so now to do it it is a bit expensive but can be done.

Comment: I guess I've never found the need for intense light in the shower. I know where it all is by feel. :P But seriously, vanity and fan lights usually cast enough light over the top of the curtain to suffice. Shower lights are fairly rare in my part of the world.

Comment: So, would something similar to https://www.amazon.com/Westinghouse-6323000-Outdoor-Dimmable-Location/dp/B01N6XHTOT/ref=sr_1_6?s=hi&ie=UTF8&qid=1540411588&sr=1-6&keywords=shower+light be appropriate? It say it is for wet locations and seals.

Comment: Yes this fixture would be legal. @isherwood the lights keep me from tripping over BIG ,,, feet,, lol

Comment: Honestly, at night it can be rather dangerous once the shampoo/conditioner is in my hair. I've had a few close calls because I couldn't see the cream-colored conditioner against the white of the bath wall. That stuff is slippery!

Comment: As I answered this is a personal preference and can be done as I have in my homes, but is more expensive and the reason that most track homes do not have wet location lighting. If you want it it can be done but the few dollars extra it costs is the reason it is not.